# Why SetWindowsPos function return false in Windows 10 and windows 11 last update?

Tags: c#, windows-10, maui, appbar, windows-11

I'm creating an AppBar in .net MAUI, and I want my app to sit at the top of the screen and reduce the working area. The area used by the AppBar shouldn't be covered by any other window.

I'm using the setWindowPos function(from user32.dll) to resize the working area, but it seems to work only on Windows 11 version 21H2. I also checked in Windows 10 versions 21H2, 22H2, and windows 11 version 22H2(+Patched) but setWindowPos returns false in all of them.

What might be the reason for this behavior? and what can I adjust in my code to make it work on other versions as well?

p.s: GetDesktopWindow and SystemParametersInfo are also from user32.dll

```
IntPtr desktopWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
var setPos = SetWindowPos(desktopWindow, IntPtr.Zero, 0, _APPBARHEIGHT, 0, 0, (uint)    (SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOSIZE | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOZORDER));//in windows 11 v21H2 return true
RECT rect = new RECT();
rect.Left = 0;
rect.Top = _APPBARHEIGHT;
rect.Right = _ScreenWidth;
rect.Bottom = _ScreenHeight - _APPBARHEIGHT;
var sysparam = SystemParametersInfo(0x002F, 0, ref rect, 0x0002);//return true
```

Thanks!

I expected the desktop working area would resize and any maximized window would not run over the AppBar
[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaicX.png). It
works as I expected in Windows 11 v21H2.

Comment: You should call [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=net-7.0) to see why it failed. Note that you will need to specify `SetLastError = true` in the DLL Import statement to make it set the last error, e.g. `[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]`

Comment: Thanks for responding!
I tried to call the GetLastWin32Error and GetLastError (from kernel32.dll) right after calling the setWindowPos, and both of them return 0.

Comment: Did you add `SetLastError = true` in the `DllImport` statement?

Comment: yes, I did add.

Comment: Are you calling GetLastWin32Error() *immediately* after calling SetWindowPos()?

Comment: yes. immediately.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT, Thanks for responding! 
demo: https://github.com/Or-Arbiv1/MauiTestSetWorkArea

Comment: I'm adding a screenshot from my windows 10 v 21H2(error1 = 0 in line 80)
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62220893/212884145-f8a616df-7148-4f0f-bc79-deae867cc26e.png